# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected, parameters in AS clause

Tags: oracle, column-alias

```
SELECT
     LMD0011M.CKEY1                             AS CDNAME 
    ,LMD0011M.CKEY1 || '\:' || LMD0011M.CDTA1    AS NMNAME 
    FROM 
     LMD0011M LMD0011M
```

The above query works fine but when I change the column names to parameters... I get an "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" error message.

```
SELECT
     LMD0011M.CKEY1                             AS :CDNAME 
    ,LMD0011M.CKEY1 || '\:' || LMD0011M.CDTA1    AS :NMNAME 
    FROM 
     LMD0011M LMD0011M

:CDNAME = CDNAME
:NMNAME = NMNAME
```

Even if I run the query in Oracle SQL Developer, I'm getting the error. I'm using Java Hibernate. How to solve this problem? Help pls

Comment: "AS" defines column labels, not variables. Is this supposed to be a PL/SQL block? Please include a more complete code sample.

Comment: Column names are fixed in a query, they are not variable. If this is about displaying column titles in your app (e.g. in a language the user chooses) have your app care about this. (Of course you can store those texts in the database, too, and have your app retrieve them, but that would be a separate query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably help if you described *why* you want to dynamically change column aliases. Personally, I don't see any valid cause to do that, but hey - if you do, no objections.

From my point of view, it is PL/SQL you need and dynamic SQL. Pass desired aliases to the procedure and return refcursor which *reflects* what you've just passed. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (alias_1 in varchar2, alias_2 in varchar2, par_rc out sys_refcursor)
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(1000);
  5  begin
  6    l_str := 'select ename as "' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(alias_1) ||'"'||
  7             ', job as "'        || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(alias_2) ||'"'||
  8             ' from emp where deptno = 20';
  9    open par_rc for l_str;
 10  end;
 11  /
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec p_test('liTTle', 'f00t', :rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :rc

liTTle     f00t
---------- ---------
SMITH      CLERK
JONES      MANAGER
SCOTT      ANALYST
ADAMS      CLERK
FORD       ANALYST

SQL>
SQL> exec p_test('brian', 'antiquena', :rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :rc

BRIAN      ANTIQUENA
---------- ---------
SMITH      CLERK
JONES      MANAGER
SCOTT      ANALYST
ADAMS      CLERK
FORD       ANALYST

SQL>
```

Comment: I'd add double quotes for the alias names. Otherwise, names like `2021` or `My Column Name` will lead to syntax errors.

Comment: Good idea, @Thorsten, thank you. Though, as I still don't see any reason why would anyone want to do it in the first place, who knows what the real requirement is.

Comment: Oh yes - DBMS_ASSERT wouldn't allow aliases you suggested anyway, @Thorsten.